# Parsing the last entry of a sar output text file to a new text file

Tags: python, bash, sar

I'm hoping to be able to collect system CPU information using sar and want to have one file where it contains all the data collected and a second file which only stores the last entry.

Output below would be my measurements.txt file

```
14:54:45        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
14:54:48        all      6.12      0.00     35.03      2.72      0.00     56.12
14:54:51        all      6.23      0.00     34.60      0.00      0.00     59.17
14:54:54        all      9.69      0.00     47.75      0.35      0.00     42.21
14:54:57        all      5.23      0.00     31.71      1.39      0.00     61.67
14:55:00        all      7.14      0.36     33.21      0.00      0.00     59.29
14:55:03        all      6.23      0.00     32.53      1.04      0.00     60.21
14:55:06        all      7.89      0.00     30.82      0.00      0.00     61.29
14:55:09        all      8.51      0.00     31.91      3.55      0.00     56.03
```

The last entry starting at 14:55:09 would be the only entry in my last_entry.txt file.

However any time I've tried to do this, I've been unable to get the last entry from the sar command in my last_entry.txt file. I've been able to send the sar output to measurements.txt file as shown in the example, however it's the last part I'm really struggling with.

At one stage, I managed to get one output to the last_entry.txt file however it wasn't the last entry, so I'm guessing that perhaps that part of my script only gets carried out once. Problem is, I don't know how to get it to continuously get the last entry until I cancel it.

Here's my code for the script which sends the output of sar to a text file and then sends the first entry instead of the last entry to the second file.

```
sar -u 3 > measurements.txt & tail -1 measurements.txt  > last_measurement.txt
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Apologies for not sharing it in my original post @KobiK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `&` command separator.  It causes the `sar` command to run in the background while you fetch the *current*  last line of its output file at some indeterminate time during its execution.  You want `sar` to finish, *then* run `tail`.

```
sar -u 3 > measurements.txt ; tail -1 measurements.txt  > last_measurement.txt
```

or more idiomatically just

```
sar -u 3 > measurements.txt 
tail -1 measurements.txt  > last_measurement.txt
```

or with `tee` to keep it all in one pipeline

```
sar -u 3 | tee measurements.txt | tail -n 1 >last_measurement.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I  tried out both of these commands and they didn't work, nothing was being written to the last_measurements.txt file, just the measurements.txt file.

Comment: Is there an empty line at the end of the `sar` output?  Does `tail -n 1 measurements.txt` also output nothing?

Comment: Making some progress here, I adjusted your last suggestion to ' sar -u 3 10 | tee measurement.txt; tail -n 1 measurement.txt > last_measurement.txt ' and this is adding the last line of the measurement.txt file which is the average of the last 30 seconds.

Comment: The `tee` is superfluous then (unless you *want* the output to the screen as well).  What you have is equivalent to the middle suggestion.